# db query error: pq: column "systemevents.receivedat" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: postgresql, group-by, postgresql-10

When running the following query I receive an error:

```
SELECT
  $__timeGroupAlias(receivedat,$__interval),
  SUBSTRING(message, '(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}') AS the_address,
  COUNT (message) AS ip 
FROM systemevents 
WHERE
  $__timeFilter(receivedat)
GROUP BY the_address
ORDER BY ip DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

#### Error

> ```
> db query error: pq: column "systemevents.receivedat" must appear 
> in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
> ```

How can I avoid this error?

I am using Grafana and PostgreSQL 10.

Comment: Like the error message says, by putting the column into the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: when i put there was aerror

Comment: Please edit the question and show the modified query and the error.

Answer (score 0):

When using "group by", then *every* column you select *must* either be used in an aggregate function or included in the "group by" clause.

Consider this query:

```
select   a, b, c
from ... 
group by a, b
```

Chances are, there will be *multiple* values of c for each combination of a and b.
*Which one* should your query return?

The database doesn't know *either* - and so throws this error.